# How to add bootstrap admin materials in Angular 4 projects?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

How to add bootstrap admin materials in Angular 4 projects?

Comment: can you explain your question clearly ?? What are you trying to do  ?

Comment: Actually, I want to add the bootstrap admin material in my angular4 project, so need a guide, how to implement it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this template CoreUI [here](https://coreui.io/demos/) or this one MDBootstrap [link here](https://mdbootstrap.com/). There are lot more available.

- there are different versions available based upon your needs
- you just have to choose the version and download the project
- you will get a demo project where you can play with it
- if you are using angular then use the following command

> npm install

- this will install all the necessary dependancies

Comment: @AnkitGupta If you accept the answer.,it will be useful for others too !! cheers